# Enable IIS Anonymous Authentication for Django App

Tags: django, authentication, iis, iis-8, windows-server

I have a Django app deployed to IIS 8.5 as two folders (code base and static files) under a site. The app includes LDAPS authentication. Therefore, I would like to enable anonymous authentication *on the app's folders* to avoid two logins for the user.

Current structure:

```
Server
    - Site
          - DjangoApp
          - DjangoAppStaticFiles
          - SomeOtherWindowsAuthenticatedApp
          - AnotherWindowsAuthenticatedApp
```

Steps I've Taken:

1. Enabled only Anonymous Authentication on `DjangoApp` and `DjangoAppStaticFiles`

This results in this error:

[image]

I then tried adding `IUSR` to both the folders in IIS and the Physical Path folder, to no avail.

What other steps do I need to take to enable Anonymous Authentication safely?

Comment: It is your Django handler that returns 401.2, so has nothing to do with IIS yet. You can only refer to Django documentation for an answer.

Comment: When using Windows authentication, the site works fine. It only shows this message when I enable Anonymous Authentication...which is why I think the Django handler is fine.